# React - Why is component not being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of `zones`, I want to display.
Now I've created a simple test. On a button a click a dummy entry should be added to the list. The variable is being updated, but the list component does not show the new entry.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FreightList from './FreightList';
import ZoneList from './ZoneList';

class FreightCapture extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            freights: props.freights,
            zones: [{ID:"1",Fracht_ID:"2",Gebiet_von:"test"}],
            freightListId: 1,
            zoneListId: 2
        };
    }

    testOnClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let newEntry = [{ID:"2",Fracht_ID:"2",Gebiet_von:"test test"}];
        this.setState({
            zones: this.state.zones.concat(newEntry)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FreightList freights={this.state.freights} parent={this} key={this.state.freightListId} />

                <ZoneList zones={this.state.zones} key={this.state.zoneListId} />
                <button onClick={this.testOnClick.bind(this)}>Test</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FreightCapture
```

ZoneList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Zone from './Zone';

class ZoneList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            zones: props.zones
        };
    }

    handleFreightClick(event) {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    Zones
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                        <table className="table table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th className="padding5px">ID</th>
                                    <th className="padding5px">Fracht_ID</th>
                                    <th className="padding5px">Land_Nr</th>
                                    <th className="padding5px">Gebiet_von</th>
                                    <th className="padding5px">Gebiet_bis</th>
                                    <th className="padding5px">Suchart_Nr</th>
                                    <th className="padding5px">Zone_Nr</th>
                                    <th className="padding5px">Zonen</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.zones.map((zone)=> {
                                  return (
                                    <Zone zone={zone} key={zone.id} />
                                  );
                                })
                            }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ZoneList
```

Zone.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Zone extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            zone: props.zone
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (

                <tr className="cursorPointer">
                    <td>
                        <div className="checkbox">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="" />
                          </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.ID }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.Fracht_ID }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.Gebiet_von }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.Gebiet_bis }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.Land_Nr }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.Suchart_Nr }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.Zone_Nr }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        { this.state.zone.Zonen }
                    </td>
                </tr>

        );
    }
}

export default Zone
```

When I click on the button, I can see the variable is being updated, but the component, which displays the list is not showing the new entry. Why?
[image]

Comment: can you show `ZoneList` component?

Comment: Can you show your zoneList component

Comment: Yes, of course. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a child component uses a local `state` you should update that `state` on each new prop received. you can do that with [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

**A followup to your comment:**
Yes, each component that "maps" the `props` it receives to its local state should set its state on each new `props` received.
I think i can see where you got confused, you mapped the `props` to the `state` in the `constructor` call, but don't forget, the constructor invoked only **ONCE**.
The `render` will get invoked on each `state` change, but you are not changing the state, hence it won't re:render it self.
The way to change the state when new `props` received is with `componentWillReceiveProps`.
With that said, i really recommend to use a `stateless` components that has no `state` nor life cycle methods where ever possible.
I recommend reading [this post](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc) by Cory House about the benefits of stateless components

Comment: Ok. I will try wiih this. So if I understood correctly, I have to implement it in ZoneList.js and Zone.js?

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine.